# React-native watchman doesn't work anymore

Tags: react-native, expo, watchman

Few days ago I noticed watchman stopped working.
Using a real android device with shake gesture I cannot Reload the app (a reload doesn't take the changes to the code). Live reload and hot reloading don't work either.

The only way I have to get the app take the changes is to kill the packager and relaunch it (often neither this method makes the app takes changes!).

There is a way I can solve? This issue It's pretty frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer to myself. After further research, this issue looks to be caused by this option in `app.json`

```
"packagerOpts": {
  "nonPersistent": "--nonPersistent"
}
```

which I've added to be able to produce a release build using Expo (otherwise I get error "`socket hang up`").
It would be nice if some Expo developer would post some infos about this issue and what that option in app.json really does (the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuration.html) says nothing).